# ReactJs webpack server is not working

Tags: reactjs, webpack

> reactjs-basic@1.0.0 start D:\ReactJsBasic\reactjs-basic
>   npm run build
>
> reactjs-basic@1.0.0 build D:\ReactJsBasic\reactjs-basic
>   webpack -d && cp src/index.html dist/index.html && webpack-dev-server --content-base src/ --inline --hot

Hash: c1a8c55592e0e9d3bcc0
Version: webpack 3.1.0
Time: 593ms
    Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
bundle.js  3.11 kB       0  [emitted]  main
   [0] ./src/app/index.js 40 bytes {0} [built]
'cp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! reactjs-basic@1.0.0 build: `webpack -d && cp src/index.html dist/index.html && webpack-dev-server --content-base src/ --inline --hot`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the reactjs-basic@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\tufan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2017-07-11T07_17_38_725Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! reactjs-basic@1.0.0 start: `npm run build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the reactjs-basic@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\tufan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2017-07-11T07_17_38_756Z-debug.log

Comment: Hi there!

In order for anyone to help you with your issue, we need to see some more details about your webpack config. 

But it looks like you're trying to run the `cp` command inside a windows shell - which isn't supported. Switch out `cp` with the npm package copy (https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy) - that should help out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reg the error:

```
'cp' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

If you are running windows then replace cp with copy.